# Some Questions about KeyEvent

Tags: java, keylistener

I was just playing around with KeyListeners, and I noticed that on most tutorials on most websites, It requires use of a JTextArea which is good for typing stuff in, but what about when you want to make, a game for instance. How would you use KeyListeners for that? Sorry in advance if the question is a little vague.

Comment: The question is not just little vague *it is rather vague*. Please define a use case. And KeyListener is not a way to go with Swing. We have Key Bindings mechanism available with much greater ease of usage

Comment: This is quite arbitrary. There is a method addKeyListener() defined for the "topmost" AWT class, java.awt.Component

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed a very vague question. Deserves a vague answer.

You can add your keylistener to a JPanel in which your game runs. Example code here: http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javagamestutorial/movingsprites/